# Why can't eventDragStop not edit the event in the callback? (FullCalendar v4)

Tags: javascript, fullcalendar, fullcalendar-4

I'm using fullcalendar (the v4 alpha) to arrange events.
I have an `eventDragStop` callback that I'm trying to use to set an extendedProp for an event, marking that the event has been altered.

```
eventDragStop: function (info) {
                        calendar.getEventById(info.event.id).setExtendedProp("extra2", true)
                }
```

Using the code above, it doesn't work. If I `alert(info.event.id)`, I can see that the correct ID is being called for the event that has been dragged, and get no errors.

If I have three events on the calendar, with IDs: 1, 2, 3, and use the following code:

```
eventDragStop: function (info) {
                        calendar.getEventById(1).setExtendedProp("extra2", true)
                }
```

So, explicitly stating to change ID number 1, rather than the event in the callback.
If I drag event number 1, this doesn't work either. However, if I drag event 2 or 3, it will work and change event 1.

Vice versa, any event I explicitly state, it will be able to change that event, providing that was not also the event that triggered the `eventDragStop` callback.

Can anyone tell me why this is?

Comment: https://fullcalendar.io/docs/v4/eventDragStop says "It is triggered before the event’s information has been modified" . So if I had to guess I'd say fullCalendar effectively overwrites any change you make here. I think this is because the event object maybe gets replaced with a new version (constructed based on its final resting place) some time after this callback runs. That's probably why dragging event 1 doesn't work, but dragging event 2 or 3 is able to update event 1 - because in that instance event 1 is not being replaced at a later time.

Comment: Personally I'd try attempting to modify the event during https://fullcalendar.io/docs/v4/eventDrop instead. This callback occurs after fullCalendar has completely finished processing the dragging/dropping and updated the event times etc. Therefore any further changes you make to the event I would expect should be preserved. ...  P.S. I've written this as a comment rather than an answer because I haven't got any proof, it's just my deduction. Try it. If it works, I'll happily add it as a proper answer...let me know how you get on.

Comment: @ADyson I was also using eventDragStop because I was checking to see whether the event was dropped outside of the calendar (temp removed for testing this issue..). I've split them out into two seperate callbacks and used eventDrop to check for adjustments as you suggested and it works perfectly. I guess the eventDragStop must be creating its own instance of the event as you suggested, then updating the real event after the callback - overwriting any changes..
Thanks!

Comment: why do you need to know if the event was dropped outside the calendar? If the user drops it outside the calendar, then simply nothing happens. You can ignore it, surely? Or are you taking that as an indication that the event should be deleted? Anyway, glad that helped you, I will write up an answer.

Comment: Correct - Dropping off the calendar to delete the event! My bad, didn't explain that bit fully.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://fullcalendar.io/docs/v4/eventDragStop says (of itself as a callback)

> "It is triggered before the event’s information has been modified"

So I think what is happening here is that fullCalendar effectively overwrites any change you make to the event data during this callback.

I think this is because the event object maybe gets replaced with a new version (constructed based on its final resting place) some time after this callback runs.
 I haven't verified this by looking at the source code but it's a logical explanation for the issue you're seeing, and it also makes some sense that the event object would get updated (with new dates/times etc) after dragging is complete, and that this might in fact involve a full refresh of the object data at that time.

Anyway, that's why when dragging event 1 you then fail to persist any updates to event 1's other data, but when dragging event 2 or 3 you are able to persist the changes to event 1 - because in that instance event 1's data is not being replaced at a later time as a result of the dragging being completed.

Instead of using `eventDragStop`, you should modify the event during `eventDrop` (https://fullcalendar.io/docs/v4/eventDrop) instead. This callback occurs after fullCalendar has completely finished processing the dragging/dropping and updated the event times etc. Therefore any further changes you make to the event data I would expect should be preserved.